# What classes and methods would one use to click select a portion on screen in java graphics then traspher it based on the object and second click?

Tags: chess, jcreator

My plan was to create an interactive chess board where, when it is your turn, you simply click on a piece then click on a position that is apart of set boundaries, in this case the different squares and rules applied to each piece is different so exactly what could I use to achieve such needed effects?

Comment: Not clear at all. Normally you would just use the mouse coordinates to calculate where you are on the board, so therefore what piece was under it. Then you'd either be selecting a piece to move, or a location to move it to.

Comment: What I ultimately meant in my question was to explain to me some code of which I can do to select then place the piece.

Comment: Well either I'm missing something or you don't know the basics of a windowing system. Which is it? To be honest I don't where to start with the latter. How have you drawn the board on the screen, and how do know what to draw, ie which pieces are where?